How to use Pearson's correlation in boostrap in python?
I have task to do in python. Here is the description:

Using the function scipy.stats.bootstrap(), perform interval estimation of the following parameters at a significance level of 1-alpha = 0.98 based on the variable sample_2: Pearson correlation coefficient.
Save the result to a variable named r_ci that contains lists with the lower and upper bounds of the confidence intervals. When calculating the value of each parameter, set the value of the function argument in scipy.stats.bootstrap() corresponding to the random number generator seed to 25.

I have trouble with my code and I tried many things. So basically I don't know how to use the Pearson correlation in bootstrap. I tried to def a function or as you can see, I tried to use it directly in arguments. For now the issue is that x and y are not the same size. Which is not true, they're both have 25 rows, no NaN. I tried many suggestions and I have different error but the same cause. This code is suppose to be really short and simple and it needs to follow the task I gave before and no changing in sample_2.
x = sp.stats.uniform.rvs(loc=-2, scale=10, size=25, random_state=34)

y = 2*x - 5 + sp.stats.norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=2, size=25, random_state=13)

sample_2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array([x, y]).T, columns=["X", "Y"])

boot_strap = sp.stats.bootstrap((sample_2['X'], sample_2['Y']), sp.stats.pearsonr, confidence_level=0.98, random_state=25)

r_ci = [boot_strap.confidence_interval[0], boot_strap.confidence_interval[1]]

print(r_ci)


Okey, the solution is to just use an argument: paired=TRUE

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
